# Differences between type variables and C++’s templates

Tags: c++, types

what is the Differences between type
variables and C++’s templates? thanks in advance

#### edited

you can see type variable in ML when function

```
fun foo x = x
```

have the type

```
a->a
```

a is type variable, can be any type

Comment: That depends a lot on what "type variables" are. Where did you come across the term?  It's not defined in the C++ Standard....

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what they have in common, we can understand you question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "what's the difference between ML's polymorphism and C++'s templates?"
They are almost entirely different, although they have some superficial similarities.

In ML,

```
fun id x = x
```

is *one* polymorphic function which has the type `a->a` (for any `a`).
In C++,

```
template<typename a>
a id(a x) { return x; }
```

is a template for generating a function of type `a (*)(a)` (for any `a` that has a copy constructor).

The template in C++ provides *compile-time polymorphism* and it needs to be instantiated for each type it's being used with. It's a "recipe" for how to generate an (overloaded) monomorphic function for a given type.

The ML function is polymorphic and works with any type, even those that haven't been thought of yet.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. Could you please provide more details?
You can try to explain what are those type variables and templates by bringing in an example ;)

I have Googled and ML is turned out to be a functional programming language.
If you are willing to know how C++’s templates might be used in a functional programming stile. You might probably like this:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
void foo()
{
    int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
    int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
}
```

Feel free to have a look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

The above describes Turing Complete compile time sublanguage of C++ :)

You can mix templates and functional programming style not only at compile time. STL(algorithms, functors, ...) quiet heavily utilizes functional programming paradigms.
So if you like functional programming you will find bunch of interesting things in C++ for you ;)

Comment: As an FYI, this probably should be a comment rather than an answer.  Answers usually try to directly answer the question, rather than commenting on it.  I know you don't have enough reputation yet to post comments, but I would avoid posting answers like this as they incorrectly make the question seem as though someone has tried to answer it.

Comment: @templatetypedef Fair enough. I know this was a comment, not an answer. Yet it is strange that I can post an answer but can’t comment. I hope I can edit and change my "comment" to answer. But the question is still not clear to me. Thanks for advising.

Answer (score 0):

C++ templates are not variables: they can't change at runtime.